# Identify filter for fish tank?

Tags: aquarium, filters, identification

I have a filter since some years now. Now I need some part for repair. But I can not find any print on it to identify the company. Maybe someone knows more about it.

It is green, looks technical similar to Eheim experience. It has 3 boxes inside for filtering materials.

What filter is it? Who sold or produced it? Any information is helpul!

[image: inside view]

[image: Side view]

[image: Top view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it at a small advertisement website. It is a Kusian product. This was a local aquarium-equipment shop, selling filters, fish, medication, decoration, gravel and similar.

[image: Kusian filter box]

Comment: i was soo close,the internal filter boxes looks to be the same even same flowrate and watt :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an ATMAN AT-3336 aquarium filter https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32731898939.html

this filter is made for aquariums up to 150 l

Not sure if you can get parts to your version of the filter.

The newer models of this filter has the same article nr AT-3336 so you can just google AT-3336 and get multiple hits.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the same as mine. Thank you for the help nonetheles!